# Every time a Specific Worksheet is Calculated in a loop Excel Crashes After 19 Iterations of loop

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My workbook I designed has a data consolidation sheet where a good amount of data is processed and organized.  This specific sheet has about 42 spill array formulas. Whenever I re-calculate the page after I open the file, the RAM usage of excel gots from about 650MB to 12GB. Then after one more calculation it maxes out at 20GB. The RAM is only 16GB and the extra 4GB is virtual memory. The reason why multiple calculations are done is because I have loop macro I made to automate a calculation necessary for my company.

Here are the spill formulas:

`=SORTBY(FILTER('Loss Template'!$E:E, ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7+1)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),""),FILTER('Loss Template'!$M:$M, ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7+1)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),""),1,FILTER('Loss Template'!$H:$H, ('Loss Template'!$A:$A=TEXT($B$2,"0"))*('Loss Template'!$F:$F<=$J$7+1)*('Loss Template'!$F:$F>=$H$7)*('Loss Template'!$H:$H>2000)*('Loss Template'!$M:$M=5),""),1)`

`=IF(G10#<>"",5,"")`

`=IF($G10#<>"",IF(XLOOKUP($G10,'Loss Template'!E:E,'Loss Template'!G:G,,0)="Closed","F","O"),"")`

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Loss Template'!E:H,MATCH(G10#,'Loss Template'!E:E,0),4),"")`

`=IF(J10#<>"",IF(J10#>'Loss Template'!$P$2,'Loss Template'!$P$2,J10#),"")`

`=IF(K10#<>"",ROUND(K10#,0),"")`

`=IF(J10#="","",IF(AND(J10#>=143000,J10#<>""),143000,J10#))`

These formulas are just copied, with slight variations in references, 4 other times on the same sheet.  In this case, is having full column references the cause of my woes? As you see here each long `sortby` has a lot of these references so I would think that could be the cause. I do know with some formulas like index you can use full column references without any calculation time loss.

Here is a screenshot of one third of the table. The magnitude of the calculations is 3 times what you see here.

[Worksheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tpm5.jpg)

Given this information, how can I reduce RAM usage to normal or manageable levels?

Comment: Why not do all the calculations in VBA where you can control how much memory is allocated and used (if done correctly)? Plus it wont look like cancer and it would be far more maintainable.

Comment: hmmm....  OK can you give me small example to work with?

Comment: No way I can un-spaghettify your formulas. But in theory you would do the sorting once, and the post process the results from there instead of calling the sort/filter multiple times.

Comment: Let me give you a piece of advise: create some names for several ranges, like `'Loss Template'!$H:$H`, `$B$2` and so on. If ever you need to modify one of these formulas between here and a year, you won't understand it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the need for whole column references in all of the applicable formulas by creating a smaller table using some the criteria in the former functions. The reason why the Ram was being over used is because the formulas were parsing from the original data set that had 50K data points per calculation. Ram was reduced to about 2.5GB consistently.

What I learned. Reduce size of dataset that needs calculating or recalculating in a loop.

Comment: If this is the answer you can mark this as solved by clicking the green checkmark next to your answer.